# ESP32-NODEMCU V1.1

Tags: arduino, esp32, nodemcu

I have the following error message occuring on the arduino IDE,

```
    Arduino: 1.8.15 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU-32S, 40MHz, 921600, None"

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/driver/include/driver/adc.h:14:0,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-adc.c:20:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/hal/include/hal/adc_types.h:90:27: error: expected ',' or '}' before '__attribute__'

     ADC_DIGI_FORMAT_12BIT __attribute__((deprecated)),  /*!<ADC to DMA data format,                [15:12]-channel, [11: 0]-12 bits ADC data (`adc_digi_output_data_t`). Note: For single convert mode. */

                           ^

cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-frame-address'

In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/hal/include/hal/dac_types.h:4:0,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/driver/include/driver/dac_common.h:16,

                 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-dac.c:22:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\expressif\esp32/tools/sdk/esp32/include/hal/include/hal/adc_types.h:90:27: error: expected ',' or '}' before '__attribute__'

     ADC_DIGI_FORMAT_12BIT __attribute__((deprecated)),  /*!<ADC to DMA data format,                [15:12]-channel, [11: 0]-12 bits ADC data (`adc_digi_output_data_t`). Note: For single convert mode. */

                           ^

cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-frame-address'

exit status 1

Error compiling for board NodeMCU-32S.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this while helping someone with a similar issue. I think you have multiple conflicting esp32 definitions in you additional boards urls. Try uninstalling the esp32 board support, changing your additional boards urls to only contain https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json, then install esp32 via boards manager again and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I fixed the problem by downloading a previous verion of the esp library.